# Randomize form order on click only in Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, random

In Microsoft Access 2010, I have a table called Items, a query of that table called Items Extended that adds a randomized number based on the ID, which looks like this

```
RandomID: Rnd([ID])
```

I then have that query open in a Split Form, called Item List, and I have made a Randomize button that just has

```
SortOrderBy RandomID
```

and that seems to work just fine.

The problem I'm running into is that it doesn't stop updating and re-sorting by the random value.

Each item in the table has an Open link that opens a Single Form called Item Details for that record with its details more easily visible and editable. But when I close it, the order re-randomizes in the Item List Split Form.

I would like to make it so that when I press the randomize button, it sorts the table in a random order, and leaves it like that until I change it to otherwise, or re-randomize it myself.

I have tried setting the split form to not Order On Load, as well as the Query. I have tried various solutions that I've seen online that involve using macros and the VGA, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it and applying it to this particular situation. I have no trouble getting a random list- I just need it to stay in the order it becomes without changing every time. I don't need it to be randomized every time I load it, just every time I hit the Randomize button.

Answer (score 0):

Try seeding your `Rnd` call with something that doesn't change, such as the currently signed-in user's id.  You need to seed `Rnd` before you use it.

I don't have any experience with Access, but a quick read through the documentation suggests that the `Rnd` function is seeded by the `Randomize` function. So you woul need to supply the current user's session as an argument to `Randomize`. See [the documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/rnd-function-HA001228901.aspx) for details of Rnd.

Comment: I believe the Autonumber ID for each field doesn't change, either, but still- I changed the value to a constant like you suggested, and the random numbers still change and re-sort when I open and close one of the Single forms.

Comment: I have updated my answer to mention how to seed the Rnd function. Hope that helps

Comment: I think I understand more now, but I'm still having trouble. If I set the Random ID field to Rnd([ID]*-1), then the random numbers will remain constant. Trouble is...they remain constant. I have the Randomize button on my form set to RunCode(RandomGen), which is a function I have in Module1.

`code`Public Function RandomGen()
Randomize
End Function`code

I've also tried making the Randomize in the function Randomize (1), Randomize (time), and other things, but none of these ever changes what the random value of each item comes out to.